# How to read a file from the Documents directory asynchronously in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, file-read

I want to read a local file stored in the Documents directory asynchronously. My code is given below:

```
-(NSString *)getLogFilePath
{
    NSString *logFileNameString = logFile;
    return  [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:logFileNameString];
}


 -(NSString *)readStringFromFile
  {
  NSString *fileAtPath =  [self getLogFilePath];
  return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSDataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  }
```

Someone please help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a typo in `NSDatadataWithContentsOfFile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Grand Central Dispatch and Block syntax to do this,

```
+(void) readStringFromFileWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success,NSString *output))completionBlock{


dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("FileReadingQueue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    // Perform long running process
    NSString *fileAtPath =  [self getLogFilePath];
    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    completionBlock(true,output);

});
```

}

Use your method,

```
[self readStringFromFileWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSString *output) {
    // use 'output' here, to get the string read from file
}];
```